# Converting hex string to ByteArray

Tags: binary, version-11.3

With blockchain support, it should finally become straightforward to convert string hashes to `ByteArray`, but I still can't figure out the canonical Wolfram way of doing it. What is the python equivalent of `bytes.fromhex` without `StringPartition[...,2]`?

Comment: The third argument of [`Hash`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hash.html) can be `"ByteArray"`

Comment: @ilian Yes, but what if I've already got a string, similar to `BlockChainData` return values?

Comment: `IntegerDigits[FromDigits[str, 16], 256, StringLength[str]/2]` would be the bytes,  then wrap `ByteArray`